# limit concurrent ssh-d connection per user via VPN client apps

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, sshd

I have a VPS (OS is Ubuntu 22.04) and added 2 users (`user1` & `user2`) to this server.
Each of these users connects to the server with "SSH-Direct" protocol in vpn client apps like NapsternetV or NetMod with user & pass.

Are there any commands or scripts to limit each user from concurrent login in multiple devices. I tried to change  `sshd_config` & `limit.conf` settings but it didn't work. Those settings seem to work just for concurrent `ssh` sessions via PuTTY and don't work for SSH-Direct connection via VPN client apps.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly did you change? How exactly did you check that the *settings works just for concurrent ssh sessions via Putty and don't work for SSH-Direct connection via VPN client apps*? What do the SSHD logs show for the connections you want to limit? Please add this information to the question, don't use comments for this purpose.